# Select a paragraph with Python + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to select a paragraph using Python + Selenium? I do the search in an input of my site, after my API return my products, I would like to click on some product, however, they are all being rendered inside a div, with the same class, since it is a for in an application SPA, how do I select the product by clicking on the paragraph of the title of the product and all have the same classes?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
driver.get("www.mysite.com.br")

select_button_input = driver.find_element_by_class_name("button-search")

select_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")
select_input.send_keys("Iphone")
select_button_input.click()
```

Below is what I want to select from my site:
[My site with products and class in my div of products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GIgB.png).

Comment: Probably you are looking for a locator for the element. Try the below xpath. (//p[text() = 'JBL'])

Comment: @Kshetra Mohan Prusty, I suspect (//p[text() = 'JBL'])  will return multiple matches

Comment: @KshetraMohanPrusty I try and return this: xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//p[text() = 'JBL'])
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Given the sshot you posted, you will need to provide more info on how you want to select the desired element. Clearly an element that contains the text "JBL" isn't unique... so are you looking for the first of it's kind or ???

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.It should work.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='card-text text-truncate']").text
print(element)
```